# Integral of functions and Infinity pointwise.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f_n : K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of bounded functions such that $\lim_n \int_K |f_n(k)|^2 dk = \infty$. My question is whether or not there exists $k_0 \in K$ such that $\lim_n f_n (k_0) = \infty$, where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I hace tried by contrareciprocal, but i think is quite difficult.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

On $[0,1]$ let $f_n(x)=0$ if $x=0$ or $x \geq \frac 1 n$ and $f(x)=n$ if $0 <x<\frac  1n$. Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ for every $x$ but $\int f_n^{2} \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K=[0,1]$ and consider the following sequence of functions :

$$f_1 = \chi_{[0,1]}$$

$$f_2 = 2\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]} \text{ , } f_3=3 \chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$$

$$f_4=4\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{3}]} \text{ , } f_5=5\chi_{[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]} \text{ , } f_6=6\chi_{[\frac{2}{3},1]}$$ and so on $\dots$

Then note that $\{f_n\}$  is a sequence of bounded functions from $[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ and $$\forall n \in \Bbb N, \exists c_n \le n  \text{ such that} \int_{0}^1 {|f_n(k)|}^2dk  = \frac{n^2}{c_n} \ge n$$. Hence,$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^1 |f_n(k)|^2dk= \infty$ but  in fact, $\{f_n(k_0)\}_{n =1}^\infty$ does not converge for any $t_0 \in [0,1]$